# How to loop through each row of gridview in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Hi I am developing one application in asp.net. I have one gridview with hiddenfield attached to it. I want to iterate through each row of the hidden field and i want to get hiddenfield value. This is my gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Name")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want javascript to iterate through each row of gridview.

```
$('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> input[type="HiddenField"]').each(function () {
              //Get hidden field value
            });
```

May i get some help how to get hiddenfield values. Thank you all

Comment: Do you mean putting $(this).val(); in the loop?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes. I want to get hidden field value. May I know if this will work? alert($(this).val());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var ResultArray =[];
$('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').find('input:hidden').each(function() {
    ResultArray.push($(this).val());
});

alert(ResultArray) // you get all hidden field value in array .
```